# mySQL use result from first select in second select

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables
what i would like to do is run a select against one and the results it returns use that for a second select query on a different table

My first select is

```
SELECT classes FROM names where initials ='".$_SESSION['username']."' order by id DESC
```

Which returns two results back, which i would like to use on a second select query

```
SELECT classes FROM classestable where classes ='results_from_first_query' order by id DESC
```

I have a select box that is populated by a select query but would like to restrict it to results the user is allowed to have access to.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT classes FROM classestable 
where classes in 
  (SELECT classes FROM names where initials ='".$_SESSION['username']."' order by id DESC)
order by id DESC
```

Comment: You should use a prepared statement, and given your rep level, you should be advocating this.